Optimization needed for unary_union function from shapely
I am curious to know if unary_union() from shapely can be optimized further in terms of speed. Is using cascaded_union from shapely a better solution or any alternate solution is available?
I want to basically get the union all geometries in a list or a geoseries. In particular we are working with polygon geometries.
from shapely.ops import unary_union

polygon_list =[ polygon1, polygon2, polygon3......]
union_polygon =unary_union(polygon_list)


Consider I have a list of list of polygons, is there an advantage of applying unary_union() over each single list or over a vectorized apply like :
def vectorized_unary_union(polygon_list):
   unary_union(polygon_list)



Looking at the code, both unary_union and cascaded_union call the same function: shapely.union_all, so they will have the same performance.

If your use case is that you need to unary_union/dissolve large numbers of polygons and you are open to use an extra library, you could try
geofileops.dissolve.
It uses geopandas and shapely (so shapely.unary_union) under the hood for dissolve, but uses some tricks (tiling the input + multiprocessing) to speed up processing datasets with many polygons. It expects the input to be in a file (a .gpkg) and writes the result to a file as well to support processing datasets larger than memory.
Disclaimer: I'm the developer of geofileops.
Sample script:
import logging
import geofileops as gfo

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Init logging so progress info is shown
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

    input_path = "C:/temp/input.gpkg"
    output_path = "C:/temp/output.gpkg"
    gfo.dissolve(
        input_path=input_path,
        output_path=output_path,
        explodecollections=True,
    )

The following benchmark gives an indication of the possible performance improvement:

